Set with elements of the form $_:[0,1] → ℝ$ defined as $_ () = ^ ~ \text{for}~\text{ all}~  ∈ [0, 1].$ is closed.
Let $$[0,1] = \{ : [0, 1] → ℝ ∶  ~\text{is}~\text{ continuous}\}$$ and
$$d_{∞}(, ) = sup\{ |() − ()|:  ∈ [0, 1]\} $$for $,  ∈ [0,1].
~\text{For}~\text{ each}~  ∈ ℕ$, define $_:[0,1] → ℝ$ by $_
() = ^
~
\text{for}~\text{ all}~  ∈ [0, 1].$
Let $ = {_:  ∈ ℕ}.$
I want to know , $P$ is closed or not.
Since only constant sequence ( $(x^k)_n$ for fixed k) are convergent sequences here and limit is also in $P$ hence $P$ is closed.
Is it correct?
Also can we say it is not open?

It is correct. No set (other than the empty set and the whole space) can be open and closed in a normed linear space (by connectedness)

You should empasize that the sequence $x^n$ is not uniformly convergent. For example the situation is different if we consider the sequence $f_n(x)=(1-x)x^n.$

The sequence converges pointwise to a discontinuous function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 \ \textrm{if}\  x\in [0,1)\\
1\  \textrm{if}\  x = 1
\end{cases}$$
so no subsequence of $(f_n)$ can converge in the norm topology. Therefore the set $\{f_n\}_n$ is closed.
Note: this is similar to $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_n$ being closed in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

How to show it is not open using only basic definition

Here is a more prosaic approach.
Suppose $g \notin P$. We want to show that there is an open ball around $g$ that does not intersect $P$. If $g(1) \neq 1$ then $B(g, {1 \over 2}|g(1)-1|)$ does not intersect $P$. So we can presume $g(1)=1$. In particular, there must be some $x^* \in (0,1)$ such that $g(x^*) >0$. Since $f_n(x^*) \to 0$ and $g \notin P$, we see that $\delta = \min_n |g(x^*)-f_n(x^*)| > 0$ and so $B(g, {1 \over 2}\delta)$ does not intersect $P$. In particular, $P^c$ is open and so $P$ is closed. Since $f_n+\epsilon \notin P$ for any $\epsilon>0$, we see that $P$ is not open.
